# How to use a list in where clause in spark-sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have data of the following format :

```
df
uid String event
a   djsan  C
a   fbja   V
a   kakal  Conversion
b   jshaj  V
b   jjsop  C
c   dqjka  V
c   kjkk   Conversion
```

I need to extract all the rows of the user whose event is conversion, so the expected outcome should be :

```
uid String event
a   djsan  C
a   fbja   V
a   kakal  Conversion
c   dqjka  V
c   kjkk   Conversion
```

I'm trying to use spark- sql for the same. I was trying to use a simple subquery of the form

```
Select * from df where uid in (Select uid from df where event = 'Conversion')
```

but this is giving me an exception.

Also I wanted to see if I had a list object of the uid, can I use that in a SQL statement and if yes, how?

```
list : List[String] = List('a','c')
```

Comment: what is the exception ?

Comment: @mrsrinivas org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unsupported language features in query: Select * from df where userid in (Select userid from df where event = 'Conversion')

Comment: what is your spark version ?

Comment: @mrsrinivas Spark 1.6.1

Comment: I think spark sql don't have support for inner queries in **below Spark 2.0**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sub query syntax you've written is not supported by spark yet. Here is how you can use your list to form a query:

```
val list = List("a","b")
val query = s"select * from df where uid in (${list.map ( x => "'" + x + "'").mkString(",") })"
```

and use it to select desired rows.

Comment: Do you have any reference regarding your statement 'sub query syntax you've written is not supported by spark yet' ?